# How to check if user Authorized or not in client side Using Jquery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-tabs, form-authentication

I am working for asp.net MVC3 Razor view. I have created for dynamically loading tabs based on each clicking of left menu.

And my jquery:

```
var form = $("ul#autotab li").click(function () {

                $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
                    tabTemplate: "<li id='" + tab_title + "'><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon1 ui-icon-close'>x</span></li>",
                    add: $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url:'/Product/GetDetailsForTab/',
                        success: function (result) {
                            $("#tabs" + counter).html(result);
                        }
                    })
                });
                $tabs.tabs("add", "#tabs" + tab_counter, tab_title);
            }
```

Here if i click one of our left menu means, I want to check if user Authorized or not in jquery tabs function. If user not Authorized means it should redirect default Log in page. I already set the Authorize attribute in`'/Product/GetDetailsForTab/'` ActionResult.

The Above code is working, but the problem is,
if not authorized means, it will redirect a Login page with in tabs content. Here i need to Redirecting page in new window instead of tabs content area.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) from Phil Haack. In it he illustrates a nice solution which allows you to prevent the forms authentication module from redirecting to the LogOn page in case of AJAX requests but return a real 401 status code that you could intercept in your client script and act accordingly.

Comment: I saw the blog post as you mentioned. i think its more closer with me, i am new in MVC3 and Jquery stuff, so i am not able to understand the full post. Can you provide some code?                                         Thanks,

Comment: I am unable to provide you with more code than what's already explained in the Phil Haack's blog post. That's all you need. If you are unable to understand this code I recommend you start reading some getting started tutorials about jQuery in the documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page Also if you have some specific question about the implementation you should not hesitate to show your progress so far and explain the difficulties you encountered. Phil Haack explained it pretty well.